# Client-side Issue: Unable to Input Registration Details After Choosing 'Register' Option in Terminal

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

> Upon selecting 'Register' in the terminal when running the client code, the system only displays "Registering with the system..." without allowing any input for the registration details.
>
> I attempted to implement a client-server application for an online banking system. When I ran the client and chose the 'Register' option, I expected to be prompted to input registration details like name, email, password, etc., but instead, the terminal just displayed "Registering with the system..." without allowing me to input any details.

> Client side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            Socket clientSocket;
            PrintWriter out;
            BufferedReader in;
            String message;
            String option;

            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8080);
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            while (true) {
                message = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);

                option = input.nextLine();
                out.println(option);

                if (option.equals("1")) {
                    registerUser(input, out, in);
                    break;
                } else if (option.equals("2")) {
                    // Implement login functionality here
                    break;
                } else if (option.equals("9")) {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid option selected.");
                }
            }

            clientSocket.close(); // Close the connection after finishing the conversation
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void registerUser(Scanner input, PrintWriter out, BufferedReader in) {
        try {
            sendMessage(out, "Enter name:");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            out.println(name);

            sendMessage(out, "Enter PPS number:");
            String ppsNumber = input.nextLine();
            out.println(ppsNumber);

            sendMessage(out, "Enter email:");
            String email = input.nextLine();
            out.println(email);

            sendMessage(out, "Enter password:");
            String password = input.nextLine();
            out.println(password);

            sendMessage(out, "Enter address:");
            String address = input.nextLine();
            out.println(address);

            // Server will handle the registration logic and respond with registration status
            String registrationStatus = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(registrationStatus);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void sendMessage(PrintWriter out, String msg) {
        out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

> Server Side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class TCPServer {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, BankUser> users;
    private ArrayList<Transaction> transactions;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public TCPServer(int port) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            users = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startServer() {
        System.out.println("Server started. Waiting for connections...");
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                handleBankingOperations(clientSocket);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int portNumber = 8080;
        TCPServer server = new TCPServer(portNumber);
        server.startServer();
    }

    public void handleBankingOperations(Socket clientSocket) {
        try {
            boolean isAuthenticated = false;
BankUser loggedInUser = null;

while (true) {
    sendMessage("Please enter 1 to Register with the system\nPlease enter 2 to Log in to the online banking system\nPlease enter 9 to Quit");
    String userInput = in.readLine();

    if (userInput.equals("1")) {
        registerUser();
    } else if (userInput.equals("2")) {
        sendMessage("Enter email:");
        String email = in.readLine();
        sendMessage("Enter password:");
        String password = in.readLine();

        loggedInUser = loginUser(email, password);
        if (loggedInUser != null) {
            isAuthenticated = true;
            sendMessage("Login successful!");
        } else {
            sendMessage("Login failed. Please try again.");
        }
    } else if (userInput.equals("9")) {
        sendMessage("Goodbye!");
        break;
    } else {
        sendMessage("Invalid option. Please try again.");
    }

    if (isAuthenticated) {
        break; // Break from the initial loop after successful authentication
    }
}

// Ensure authentication was successful before proceeding
if (isAuthenticated) {
    while (true) {
        sendMessage("Please enter 1 to Register with the system\nPlease enter 2 to Log in to the online banking system\nPlease enter 9 to Quit");
        String userInput = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received user input: " + userInput);

        if (userInput.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("User selected option 1: Register");
            registerUser();
        } else if (userInput.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("User selected option 2: Login");
            // ... (existing code remains unchanged)
        } else if (userInput.equals("9")) {
            sendMessage("Goodbye!");
            System.out.println("User selected option 9: Quit");
            break;
        } else {
            sendMessage("Invalid option. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("Invalid option: " + userInput);
        }
    }
}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        try {
            sendMessage("Enter name:");
            String name = in.readLine();

            sendMessage("Enter PPS number:");
            String ppsNumber = in.readLine();

            sendMessage("Enter email:");
            String email = in.readLine();

            sendMessage("Enter password:");
            String password = in.readLine();

            sendMessage("Enter address:");
            String address = in.readLine();

            double initialBalance = 0.0;

            BankUser newUser = new BankUser(name, ppsNumber, email, password, address, initialBalance);
            users.putIfAbsent(email, newUser);

            sendMessage("User registered successfully!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private BankUser loginUser(String email, String password) {
        BankUser user = users.get(email);
        if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return user;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void lodgeMoney(BankUser user) {
        try {
            sendMessage("Enter amount to lodge:");
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());

            user.deposit(amount);

            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(user, "Lodged money", amount);
            transactions.add(transaction);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void retrieveAllUsers() {
        // Logic to retrieve and display all registered users
    }

    private void transferMoney(BankUser sender) {
        try {
            sendMessage("Enter recipient's email:");
            String recipientEmail = in.readLine();
            BankUser recipient = users.get(recipientEmail);

            if (recipient != null) {
                sendMessage("Enter amount to transfer:");
                double amount = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());

                if (sender.getBalance() >= amount) {
                    sender.withdraw(amount);
                    recipient.deposit(amount);

                    Transaction transaction = new Transaction(sender, recipient, "Transferred money", amount);
                    transactions.add(transaction);
                } else {
                    sendMessage("Insufficient funds for transfer.");
                }
            } else {
                sendMessage("Recipient not found.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void viewAllTransactions() {
        // Logic to view all transactions
    }

    private void updateUserPassword(BankUser user) {
        try {
            sendMessage("Enter new password:");
            String newPassword = in.readLine();

            user.setPassword(newPassword);

            sendMessage("Password updated successfully!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String msg) {
        out.println(msg);
    }
}
```